# Does Elasticsearch reindex the documents automatically each time I update them

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a social model where users can like photos.

My  photo document looks like this :

```
{
"id" : ... //Indexed
"url": ...
"likes": .. //Not indexed
//Other properties
}
```

My question is, as long as a photo gets likes from other users I have to update my document. Does this update make elasticsearch automatically reindex it (knowing that the "likes" property is NOT indexed in my mapping) or it's done only if my indexed properties have changed?

My concern is performance here.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) ;-) But yes, as soon as you change a single field of your source document, the document is reindexed anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document in elasticsearch are immutable. Updating a document is always a reindexing and it consist of the following steps:

- Retrieve the JSON (that you want to reindex)
- Change it
- Delete the old document
- Index a new document

[Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_updating_documents.html)