# Elasticsearch - How to update document

Tags: elasticsearch

How does elasticsearch update document? It will delete original document and make new one? I've heard this is how nosql's updating method. does elasticsearch do, same as any other nosql db? or It will replace/insert just field which need to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Elasticsearch reindex the documents automatically each time I update them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749633/does-elasticsearch-reindex-the-documents-automatically-each-time-i-update-them)

Answer (score 6):

For example, I'm running with Elasticsearh 7.0.0.
First, I created one document,

**PUT /employee/_doc/1**

```
{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Snow",
    "age" : 19,
    "about" : "King in the north",
    "sex" : "male"
}
```

Then I updated it via

**POST /employee/_update/1/**

```
{
    "doc": {  
        "first_name" : "Aegon",
        "last_name" : "Targaryen",
        "skill": "fighting and leading"
    }
}
```

Finally, I got correct result when

**GET /employee/_doc/1**

```
{
    "_index" : "employee",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_version" : 9,
    "_seq_no" : 11,
    "_primary_term" : 1,
    "found" : true,
    "_source" : {
        "first_name" : "Aegon",
        "last_name" : "Targaryen",
        "age" : 19,
        "about" : "King in the north",
        "sex" : "male",
        "skill" : "fighting and leading"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kalehmann for your edit! I missed the format of my codes. Your help makes the answer easy to read.

Comment: This worked for me -- thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Document in elasticsearch are immutable object. Updating a document is always a reindexing and it consist of the following steps:

- Retrieve the JSON (that you want to reindex)
- Change it
- Delete the old document
- Index a new document

[Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_updating_documents.html)

Answer (score 1):

For the answer you can check the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html):

> In addition to being able to index and replace documents, we can also
> update documents. Note though that Elasticsearch does not actually do
> in-place updates under the hood. Whenever we do an update,
> Elasticsearch deletes the old document and then indexes a new document
> with the update applied to it in one shot.

Comment: The link seems to be broken.